# Excel VBA: Error 0x800c00008

Tags: excel, vba

I made a small macro in Excel that helps find IANA TimeZone names from timezonedb.com using API. I made it work for my PC, but when someone else used it from their PC, it began showing an error like this

[image: error message]

I've found solutions over the internet saying that the Microsoft Core Package has to be repaired, but I want to know if I could bypass that by adding something in the code, maybe? Is there a way to accomplish that?

I'm adding the function code here:

```
Function FetchTZ(qLat As Double, qLong As Double, c_check As String, rN As Integer) As String        
    Dim JSON_content As String
    Dim IANAtz As String
    Dim temp_l As Long
    Dim XMLobj As Object
    Dim qURL As String
    Dim CheckCountry As String

    temp_l = 0
    JSON_content = vbNullString

    qURL = "https://api.timezonedb.com/v2/get-time-zone?key=NB7W9T1K95UT&format=json&by=position&lat=" & qLat & "&lng=" & qLong
    Set XMLobj = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    With XMLobj
        .Open "POST", qURL, False
        .send
        JSON_content = .responseText
    End With
    Set XMLobj = Nothing

    temp_l = InStr(1, JSON_content, "zoneName")
    IANAtz = Mid(JSON_content, (temp_l + 11), ((InStr(temp_l, JSON_content, "abbreviation") - 3) - (temp_l + 11)))

    IANAtz = Replace(IANAtz, "\/", "/")

    temp_n = InStr(1, JSON_content, "countryCode")
    CheckCountry = Mid(JSON_content, (temp_n + 14), 2)


    If CheckCountry <> c_check And Len(c_check) = 2 Then
        Sheets("TZMacro").Range(Cells(rN, 1), Cells(rN, 4)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If

    FetchTZ = IANAtz
```

Thanks in advance and I really hope you can teach me how to crack this one!

Comment: Your code works fine with a 0, 0 for latitude and longitude. I get the response: `{"status":"OK","message":"","countryCode":"YE","countryName":"Yemen","zoneName":"Asia\/Aden","abbreviation":"+03","gmtOffset":10800,"dst":"0","dstStart":-719636812,"dstEnd":0,"nextAbbreviation":"","timestamp":1500646117,"formatted":"2017-07-21 14:08:37"}`. Suggest that you tested the code so many times that you got rate limited i.e. you only can call the API so many times per day etc.

Comment: Sounds like a fair point. I'll think about that and maybe build something from the idea. Thanks a lot, Robin!

Comment: Please post an answer to this so it no longer appears in the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

to

CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

and the error didn't pop up anymore.